# Safari completely white when in foreground

Tags: safari, ventura

On a Mac Mini 2018 running the current stable Ventura 13.5.1, I am having the issue that Safari (v16.6) often only shows the page for a split second after loading, then the content goes white. When I then put a different window into the foreground, the content becomes visible, and when I put Safari into the foreground, it goes white again. Despite the white page, links are correctly detected when hovering, clickable and navigable - you only have to know where the link is that you want to click, because you don't see anything on the screen.

The issue already occurred on a freshly installed 13.3.1 and was not fixed by system updates (13.5 and 13.5.1).

I wonder what could be the cause and whether there's a solution for this?

Comment: Have you installed any extensions? It's very likely an issue on your machine, rather than a 'bug' with Safari (otherwise lots of people would be reporting the same thing). Check whether the problem occurs in Safe Boot mode, and in a new user account.

Comment: The issue occurs in a new user account as well. No Safari extensions are installed. I will try safe mode.

Comment: Is it a specific webpage, or every one? What size is your display? Can you show a screenshot of the entire screen when this happens? (Try not to include anything personal !)

Comment: More information toward the question. This happens to me on sites that are heavy on javascript. For instance, this one (StackExchange) seems to display and operate fine, but something I know is javascript heavy like Heroic.com or Facebook, etc., turn blank after ever so briefly displaying the page. This leads me to believe there's an issue with loading JS.

no extensions
Ventura 13.6.4 on an Intel Mac
have NOT seen this on my M1 or M2 Pro Macs
bringing ANY window into the foreground causes the browser to display its content which blanks out again when (re-)foregrounding the browser.